# Angular i18n metadata separately

Tags: angular, internationalization

It is well known that in Angular you have to specify translation metadata in `i18n` and `i18n-*` attributes. However providing meaning and description can quickly bloat my template if it has several labels. Is there a way for these attributes to refer to some other resource instead, e.g. a json file that is next to the template with a certain naming convention?